# Receiving error "Not a WebDAV-enabled share"

Tags: nautilus, webdav

I am developing a website using a host that has provided a link (through a cpanel interface) to open the server storage from my computer. I have been using one computer with Fedora 20 on it. This has been working well for some time. I am trying to use an Ubuntu computer, in another location with a different router and internet provider. When I try to open the link in the file browser, I am receiving an error saying "Not a WebDAV-enabled share". I have researched this and all the sites I have found say this means the server isn't setup to allow WebDAV. However, I am only trying to open a connection which works on another system, and works well.

Is there a way to solve this problem? Does it require further setup on my Ubuntu machine? Or does it mean there is another reason for this problem?